# Difference between Date parse and differencing the date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Return the number of milliseconds between January 1, 1970 and given date.

Using Date.Parse Method to compare the Dates:

```
var fromdt="2013/05/29";
var todt="2013/05/29";
var d = Date.parse(fromdt);
var e = Date.parse(todt);
if(d==e)
{
    alert("Both the Dates are equal!");
}
else if(d>e)
{
    alert("From date should not be greater than todate!");
}
else if(d<e)
{
 alert("Valid Dates");
}
```

Also using - operator to compare the dates:

```
var dt_from = new Date("2013/05/25");
var dt_to=new Date("2013/05/24");

if(dt_from-dt_to == 0)
{
alert("Both dates are Equal!");
}
else if(dt_from-dt_to > 0)
{
alert("From date should not be greater than todate!");
}
else if(dt_from-dt_to < 0)
{
alert("Okay!");
}
```

Also this will provide the difference in milliseconds. 
Then, what is the difference between the 2 codes?I mean Date.parse and new Date()..Thank you....

Comment: This is the third time that you have asked this question.

Comment: @undefined, I hope he will get mass of downvotes so he will learn, the hard way.

Comment: remove my DOwnVotes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print following commands in browser console and you can see diference:

1) `Date.parse("2013/05/29")` //return number of milliseconds between January 1, 1970  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

2) `new Date("2013/05/25")` //return DateTime object